# What is the best way to move a regular writing workshop online?

Tags: software, tools

Given the ongoing efforts to reduce close personal contact with others due to COVID-19, I am seeking suggestions for the best way to conduct writing workshop groups online. This is usually a physical gathering for writers to brainstorm, share, and critique with guidance. I know that Zoom is free and could facilitate video calls for everyone. What about sharing or editing/reviewing written work among the group? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Haven't done it myself, so this is far from authoritative, but just a couple points to note: Zoom is somewhat limited (in number of participants and duration) in its free version; Discord might serve you better.  For real-time editing and sharing, Google Docs and similar applications work fairly well in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs is a free and user-friendly way to share writing, collaborative edits, and comments. You could have that (or any similar web application) up on the screen, while on a call, to approximate the experience of being in a room together with printed writings.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me Skype does all of the above. It has call, video call, text and file sharing features all built in.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Groups are worth trying, my UK Small Business group has 600+ members.

Comment: I don't see how your example of a "small business group" is applicable to OP's situation. Could you elaborate?